# Two joomla components causing Javascript conflict

Tags: javascript, google-maps, joomla

I use the iCagenda component for event mgt. I installed the Phocamaps component and modified it to display iCagenda events as markers. I didn't alter anything Java related. Just some database calls.

I have a footer module which then displays the map and everything is working great. However, I just noticed that on event pages where the event extension displays a map, the footer map then either does not display markers, or the map is simply blank.

You can see here

http://dev.pfp-consortium.org/index.php/events/4-advanced-distributed-learning-workshop

All pages work fine except event pages, in which case the footer shows map with no markers.

The event developer said it is a phoca issue: Here is what he said.

"It is a bug of phoca map (i've seen this bug in many google maps module).

The issue is that a google map api could be loaded only one time.
If you look at iCagenda code, you will see that iCagenda controls if google api not loaded before (not possible to check an extension loaded after, as it is the case with your module phoca) and doesn't load if already loaded.

My code to prevent this :

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$scripts = array_keys($document->_scripts);
$mapsgooglescriptFound = false;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($scripts); $i++)
{
    if (stripos($scripts[$i], 'maps.googleapis.com') !== false)
    {
    $mapsgooglescriptFound = true;
    }
}
if (!$mapsgooglescriptFound)
    {
    $document->addScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false');
    }
```

"

The phoca developer seems to think it is caused by the other extension. I could not find a place in the phoca code to even make an edit like indicated above.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). You might get answers there. Please consider moving your question there (delete it from [SO] and paste question text at joomla.stackexchange.com).